# Make server-sided client-list threadsafe in SignalR?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, signalr

I am trying to make my server-side thread safe.

Currently, I am using a `List<ServerClient> m_connectedClients` and fill it with my clients when they connect or disconnect, like this:

```
    public LoginStatus Connect(string connectionId, LoginRequestMessage message)
    {
        var status = m_databaseManager.CheckLogin(message.Username, message.Password);
        if (status == LoginStatus.Success)
        {
            var connection = m_connectedClients.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Username == message.Username);
            if (connection == null)
            {
                var client = m_databaseManager.GetClient(message.Username, connectionId);
                m_connectedClients.Add(client);
            }
            else if (!connection.ConnectionIds.Contains(connectionId))
            {
                connection.ConnectionIds.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }

    public void Disconnect(string connectionId)
    {
        foreach (var connection in m_connectedClients.Where(p => p.ConnectionIds.Contains(connectionId)))
        {
            connection.ConnectionIds.Remove(connectionId);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected... {0}", connectionId);
    }
```

In my scenario in some cases I would like to do things like this:

```
    public bool IsLoggedIn(string connectionId)
    {
        if (m_connectedClients.Any(p => p.ConnectionIds.Contains(connectionId)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

So, simply adding and removing things with a ConcurrentDictionary will probably not work (I even dont know, what key I would use, since I could have more than one ConnectionId per client and that's the only identifier I have here.

What I could do is lock the `List<ServerClient>` every time I access it, but that would be in alot of places with alot of locks, so I guess thats a terrible idea, right?

Another question is:
Do I have to be thread safe everywhere? Or is it only important when connecting (adding) and disconnecting (removing), but not, when actually working with that list?

Answer (score 1):

> So, simply adding and removing things with a ConcurrentDictionary will probably not work (I even dont know, what key I would use, since I could have more than one ConnectionId per client and that's the only identifier I have here.

You are right. ConcurrentDictionary could be too limited for your use case.

> What I could do is lock the List every time I access it, but that would be in alot of places with a lot of locks, so I guess thats a terrible idea, right?

There is no way around it: every time you access the list you should take a lock. Make a class that provides the functionality that required the list and put the lock and acquiring the locks there so that acquiring locks is not scattered around the code and maybe accidentally forgotten.

> Another question is: Do I have to be thread safe everywhere? Or is it only important when connecting (adding) and disconnecting (removing), but not, when actually working with that list?

Being threadsafe is a global property. If you are not threadsafe everywhere, then you are not threadsafe period. If you have many readers and read operations and only few writers and write operations, then consider using the ReaderWriterLockSlim class that is optimized for such scenarios. You have to use it every time you access the list though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I use Resharper, I won't forget my locks anyway. But what do you mean with the class anyway? For example, I cannot simply wrap the lists FirstOrDefault() method and add a lock inside that method, because there might be some other statements after the FirstOrDefault() (e.g. a Remove()-call) relying on the lock. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Jannik: I mean capturing all access to the connectedClients in a ConnectedClients class that has methods like "AddClient"  so that access to the connectedClientList is funneled through this class and that class takes care of all necessary locks. This was triggered by your remark that you mention you'll have to lock in "alot of places". So yes, there will be locking often, but the technicality of locking is encapsulated in that class.